# How to track how long some Mongo queries take

Tags: mongodb

I have a few Mongo queries in the JS format, such as:

```
db.hello.update(params,data);
```

How do I run them in such a way that I can see exactly how long they've taken to run later?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, perhaps if you add more detail about your goals we can help find a solution.

Comment: I want to know how long some Mongo updates take to run.

Comment: How to find execution time for updateOne operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Do your updates with safe=true, which will cause the update call to block until mongod has written the data (the exact syntax for this depends on the driver you're using). You can add timing code around your updates in your application code, and log as appropriate.
2. Enable verbose (or more-verbose) logging, and use the log files to determine the time spent during your updates. See [the mongo docs on logging](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging) for more information.
3. Enable the profiler, which stores information about queries and updates in a capped collection, `db.system.profile`, including the time spent servicing the query or update. Note that enabling the profiler affects performance, though not severely. See [the mongo docs on profiling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) for more information.